# how to convert dict items into sentence

Tags: python

I have a input data with two dict index and notes.

```
indexes={'Laptops':'1','Mob':'2','Cars':'3','Bus':4}
    Notes={
 

   
    'indexs':[1,3],
    'Laptops':[
        "dell","asus","acer"
    ],
    'Mob':[
        "mi","realme"
    ],
   'Bus':[
     "aB"
 
   ],
    'Cars':["Not found"
         ]

}
```

Created a sentence generator

```
def SenGen(alpha,beta):
    for a,b in alpha.items():
        for c,d in beta.items():
            if c in a:
                print(f"{a} are ", end="")
                for i, e in enumerate(b):
                    if i == len(b)-1:
                        print(f"and {e}. ", end="")
                    elif i == len(d)-2:
                        print(f"{e} ", end="")
                    else:
                        print(f"{e}, ", end="")
```

with the help of SenGen, i generated a sentence which is shown below.

```
SenGen(Notes,indexes)
```

output

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus are and aB. Cars are and not found.
```

in the above output in **laptops i have 3 words which is seprated by 'and'**,**In mob i have two words which is separated by 'and' **.While in the **Bus i have only one word. but 'and' is front of aB**, and in thecase of its same  **cars i have not found**.

my desired output should be like shown below.

output:

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus are aB. Cars are  not found.
```

i followed set of cases to fix that issue shown below.

```
1.if i == len(b)==1:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")

2.if i == len(b)==0:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")
3.if i == len(b)<1:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")
4.if i == len(b)>1:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")
```

but im unable to solve it.

Comment: For what reason do you have the `indexes` variable? What is its purpose?

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo it is used to execute the method `SenGen`
@Oj I find it impressive what you've written so far since it seems you are new to Python. But your specification is all over the place and I would rethink the concept.

Comment: Indexes for searching keys in In Notes

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem by relying on lists and its methods in Python:

```py
keys = list(Notes.keys())
keys.remove('indexs')

for key in keys:
    first_clause = ', '.join(Notes[key][:-1])
    last_clause = Notes[key][-1:][0]
    
    if len(first_clause) == 0:
        print(key + ' is ', last_clause, end='. ')
    else:
        print(key + ' are ', first_clause, ', and ', last_clause, end='. ')
```

Then your output is:

```
Laptops are  dell, asus , and  acer. Mob are  mi , and  realme. Bus is  aB. Cars is  Not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate before.

```py
def SenGen(alpha,beta):
    for a,b in alpha.items():
        for c,d in beta.items():
            if c in a:
                print(f"{a} are ", end="")
                if len(b) == 1:
                    print(f"{e}. ", end="")
                else:
                    for i, e in enumerate(b):
                        if i == len(b)-1:
                            print(f"and {e}. ", end="")
                        elif i == len(d)-2:
                            print(f"{e} ", end="")
                        else:
                            print(f"{e}, ", end="")
```